# Is there any way to look deeper at a specific wallet address to see if it's associated with any other BTC balances

Tags: address, public-key

I recently switching mining pools and desktop wallet (Sparrow). In an effort to set the address I sent a small amount of BTC to an address thinking it was my own, in a newly set up Sparrow wallet. Unfortunately it didn't end up in that wallet and now I'm extremely confused. The address I sent to was a BTC address and I can see it was transacted on the Explorer... I would have cut and paste the send to address from my Sparrow wallet but when I look at my addresses section I don't see any of the addresses in my sparrow desktop app for any wallet. Is there any way to look deeper at a specific wallet address to see if it's associated with any other BTC balances which may give me a clue to where I sent it? Maybe I sent it to a different wallet of mine... I don't know where else the send to address would have come from?

Answer (score 0):

You can type the address into a [blockchain explorer](https://www.google.com/search?q=blockchain+explorer) to get a list of transactions and total balance.